# Calling View from another view is that good idea?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to create one view in which I need to take data from another view i.e from V_View1
as per following example

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View_GlobalView]
as 
select Tb1.Id, Tb1.SampleNo, Tb1.JobNo, V1.Action  from [tableName] As Tb1
left outer join 
(select * from V_view1 ) as V1
ON Tb1.Id = V1.Id and Tb1.SampleNo = V1.SampleNo
```

`V_view1` returns large amount of data so use of that view in another view is that good idea?

will it take more time to execute ?

Comment: You don't *call* a view - you simply reference it; it's perfectly fine to reference one view from another, however this level of abstraction is ultimately not desireable and can lead to the query optimizer being unable to build an optimal execution plan. YMMV so test, test, test.

Comment: IMHO, nested views should be avoided for the reasons @Stu mentioned, at least when performance is a consideration. Not only does this challenge the optimizer, compilation costs will be higher than without nesting.

Comment: Yes, I removed that reference and check performance is imporved. Thank you...!!